# Style based on style set on window not shown in Designer (only in runtime)

Tags: c#, wpf

Quite odd scenario. I have the following App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="BrokenBG.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="WindowStyleBase" TargetType="ContentControl" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
          </Style>
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WindowStyleBase}" />

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And a plain empty window with the style set:

```
<Window x:Class="BrokenBG.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I run the app all is fine. I see the red bg.
But I cannot see it in the designer. The code above is a repro case I've experienced in another larger project.

When I change Window Style from `WindowStyle` to `WindowStyleBase` then I can directly see the red background color in the designer.

Can this be fixed? My windows have a dark theme, therefore I cannot design the views in Visual Studio / Blend since the background is white and black during runtime (my text is white)

It looks like the designer has issues with BasedOn parsing? (unsure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that works, even though it won't compile.
You can change staticresource in the based on to dynamic resource.

It'll suddenly start working in designer, but this won't compile.

I even changed red to blue, and the designer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll that try since there is no other option. But fixing one bug with another seems odd :/

Comment: Well I can confirm this workaround as it seems to work. If no explanation is going to come up I'll mark this as an answer. Thanks