# Using CollectionViewSource instead of collection directly breaks Visual Studio Designer View? Fixable?

Tags: c#, wpf

Well, I am out of luck since many things I do break the designer somehow ([Other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253741/style-based-on-style-set-on-window-not-shown-in-designer-only-in-runtime))

When I use a collection in a datagrid view I can see in the designer all the dummy content rows I've generated, this stops to work however when I add a collection view source to group the data. Then the entire collection is only shown at runtime.

Is this another issue with WPF designer?

Repro code:

View:

```
<Window x:Class="CollectionViewSourceDesignerBreak.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:collectionViewSourceDesignerBreak="clr-namespace:CollectionViewSourceDesignerBreak" >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <collectionViewSourceDesignerBreak:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Entries}" x:Key="Cvs">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

    </Window.Resources>


    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <!--<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Cvs}}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">-->

    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Dummy View Model:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace CollectionViewSourceDesignerBreak
{
    public class VMData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MoreInfo { get; set; }

    }
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<VMData> _entries = new ObservableCollection<VMData>();
        public ObservableCollection<VMData> Entries
        {
            get { return _entries; }
            set { _entries = value; }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Entries.Add(new VMData{Name="A", MoreInfo = "Some text"});
            Entries.Add(new VMData{Name="B", MoreInfo = "More text"});
            Entries.Add(new VMData{Name="A", MoreInfo = "Other text"});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment the Cvs line in and the other out and the content is gone in the designer.

Comment: It's a guess but I'm pretty sure that Resources don't inherit `DataContext`. You could use `d:DesignTimeDataContext`, because that would override `DataContext` at designtime.

Comment: There is no such thing as a DesignTimeDataContext, only d:DataContext. I've set it on window but no effect.

Comment: I'm looking into it, perhaps I am confusing it with Silverlight.

Comment: I have a designtime workaround, but the downside is that it doesn't work at runtime :S Use a name too `<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Entries}" x:Key="Cvs" x:Name="Cvs">` + `ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Cvs}"`

Comment: It does not work for me in the designer. I see the auto generated column headers (that's indeed new) but the 3 sample data entries are not visible. Are they visible for you?

Comment: They are indeed visible to me, but I am using VS2012 pro with update 3, that could be different from yours.

Comment: So am I. Did you use my sample class above, do you have AutoGenerateColumns set to true? I've double-checked everything and I do only see the headers. Additionally if the name is differs between Name and Key then ElementName=CvsKey does not even show the headers.

Comment: I started a new wpf application in VS2012 and copied your data. Perhaps I can find another solution tonight. I was thinking about attached properties which check designtime status.

Comment: Aah, found the issue, I still had the d:DataContext set for the designer. Without it I can see the entries too :)

Comment: It's a darn strange thing, but somehow I feel there must be a working alternative. Glad you have some designer support after all :)